# How do we calculate monthly sale in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have trouble with some calculation in Codeigniter.  Please check attached image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK23L.jpg

That data fetching from the database , the sale column is fine but I having trouble with monthly sale

1st day of every month sale (10) and monthly sale (10) are same, but from second day sale is correct(8), monthly sale has to be 1st day sale + second day sale(10+8 = 18). for third day sale is fine, monthly sale should be (18+20=38). the calculation going like this up to end of the month, Same process again stating from next month

How do we calculate in codeigniter, The above image i have created in excel sheet for demonstration purpose.

Model view

```
    public function fetchSaleData()
{
    $this->db->join('stock_shop','stock_shop.shop_id = stock_sale.shopId');
    $this->db->join('stock_products','stock_products.product_id = stock_sale.productID');
    $thisMonth=date('m');
    $this->db->where('MONTH(DateOfSale)',$thisMonth);  
    $query= $this->db->get("stock_sale");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

controller view

```
public function salesView()
    {
        $data['sales']=$this->Query_sale->fetchSaleData();
        $data['shops']=$this->Query_sale->fetchShop();
        $this->load->view('stock/shop_sales_view',$data);

    }
```

Comment: i think get all no of rows then use php

Comment: Can you please elaborate bit more?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

since you're not showing table structures or any other insight, I'll only suggest an approach based on my own code which you may feel free to adapt to your specific needs, along with the assumptions I make along the way

**Assumption #1: the model returns an array in which each element contains the date and the sold units on such date**

This would look like this

```
+-----------------+
|    array data   |
+------------+----+
| 2020-01-01 | 10 |
+------------+----+
| 2020-01-02 | 20 |
+------------+----+
| 2020-01-03 |  5 |
+------------+----+
| 2020-01-04 |  8 |
+------------+----+
```

On array form, this may look like this:

```
$ar = array(
    0 => array(
        'date'          => '2020-01-01',
        'units_sold'    => 10,
    ),

    1 => array(
        'date'          => '2020-01-02',
        'units_sold'    => 20,
    ),

    2 => array(
        'date'          => '2020-01-03',
        'units_sold'    => 5,
    ),

    3 => array(
        'date'          => '2020-01-04',
        'units_sold'    => 8,
    ),
);
```

and so on until the end of the month. Lets call the returned fields `date` and `units_sold` as in the above example

now that you have the data loaded in a variable (`$ar`) you can loop through it and keep tabs on the accumulated total on each loop.

```
$accum = 0; // keep track of accumulated total
$i = 0; // keep track of array index

foreach ($ar as $a)
{
    $accum += $a['sales'];
    $ar[$i]['accum'] = $accum;
    $i++;
}
```

Upon running, this code will:

- Iteration 0: For 2020-01-01, sales=10, accumulated=10
- Iteration 1: For 2020-01-02, sales 20, accumulated=30
- Iteration 2: For 2020-01-03, sales 5, accumulated=35
- ...and so on until the month is over

The above can be verified with a `print_r` or `var_dump` (I use print_r... like this: `print print_r($ar,true);`):

**print_r output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-01-01
            [sales] => 10
            [accum] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-01-02
            [sales] => 20
            [accum] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-01-03
            [sales] => 5
            [accum] => 35
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-01-04
            [sales] => 8
            [accum] => 43
        )

)
```

So, now that you've succesfully pushed a whole new element in your result array, you can send it over to the view and display it in tabular form as you need